# Why is "Future() is Future" false?

Tags: python

I am very confused that this is not working as I expected:

```
from concurrent.futures import Future

f = Future()

print(type(f))

if f is Future:
   print("Future")
else:
   print("Other")
```

The output is:

```
<class 'concurrent.futures._base.Future'>
Other
```

While I was expecting:

```
<class 'concurrent.futures._base.Future'>
Future
```

What is going on? Why isn't `f is Future` true?

Comment: `is` is used to check if two objects have the same identity, not if one is an instance of the other. Use `isinstance`.

Comment: @AndrewLi your comment looks like an answer to me!

Comment: @purpleTentacle are you from C# background? C# `is` checks types.

Comment: yes! it seems that I am mixing c# and python today! Thanks! @AndrewLi: I would write that as an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#is):

> ### 6.10.3. Identity comparisons
>
> The operators `is` and `is not` test for object identity: `x is y` is true if and only if *x* and *y* are the same object. Object identity is determined using the [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#id) function. `x is not y` yields the inverse truth value.

Thus, `is` does not check if an object is an instance of a class but if two objects have the same identity. For that you use the builtin function [`isinstance(instance, class)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
if isinstance(f, Future):
```